# Can I reduce code duplication, without unduly compromising efficieny or introducing overheads?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-cursor

My problem is centered around having code that is easily maintained and efficient. More specifically it revolves around getting data from an SQLite Cursor.

When I first started using cursors I would hard code something along the lines of `mystrvar = cursor.getString(?)` where **?** would be the offset to the respective row.

I then started using constants that were defined along with the table column names. e.g. I'd have something like :-

```
// Table Aisles
    public static final String AISLES_TABLE_NAME = "aisles";
    public static final String AISLES_COLUMN_ID = PRIMARY_KEY_NAME;
    public static final String AISLES_COLUMN_ID_FULL = AISLES_TABLE_NAME + AISLES_COLUMN_ID;
    public static final int AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX = 0; ........
```

and, as an example would code something along the lines of :-

`mystrvar = cursor.getString(DBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX)`;

This was an improvement, but had the flaw of not being that good at coping with joined tables.

I then became aware of `cursor.getColumnIndex()`, BUT suspected that solely using this. Would have overheads that could be circumvented.

What I have done is to include code that has sparse use of `getColumnIndex()`. It sets ***offset*** variables via `getColumnIndex()` just once in an activity/custom cursor adapter and subsequently uses the respective ***offset*** variable which is the cursor offset for the respective column.

The following is an example (split into 3 chunks, the variable definitions, second a method that sets the variables and then third, the actual data extraction from the cursor :-

1) variable definitions :-

```
public class Database_Inspector_AislesDB_Adapter extends CursorAdapter {

    // Variables to store aisles table offsets as obtained via the defined column names by
    // call to setAislesOffsets (aisles_aisleid_offset set -1 to act as notdone flag )
    public static int aisles_aisleid_offset = -1;
    public static int aisles_aislename_offset;
    public static int aisles_aisleorder_offset;
    public static int aisles_aisleshopref_offset;

    public Database_Inspector_AislesDB_Adapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        setAislesOffsets(cursor); //** Calls method to set offsets
    ........ 
}
```

2) Method that sets the offsets just once *(returns virtually immediately if they have already been set)*

```
    // Set Aisles Table query offsets into returned cursor, if not already set
    public void setAislesOffsets(Cursor cursor) {
        if(aisles_aisleid_offset != -1) {
            return;
        }
        aisles_aisleid_offset = cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID);
        aisles_aislename_offset = cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_NAME);
        aisles_aisleorder_offset = cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ORDER);
        aisles_aisleshopref_offset = cursor.getColumnIndex(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP);
    }
```

3) example use of offsets

```
        textviewaisleid.setText(cursor.getString(aisles_aisleid_offset));
        textviewaislesaislename.setText(cursor.getString(aisles_aislename_offset));
        textviewaislesorder.setText(cursor.getString(aisles_aisleorder_offset));
        textviewaisleshopref.setText(cursor.getString(aisles_aisleshopref_offset));
```

However, the above coding has to be used for each activity/adapter that uses the table table. There are 7 tables with 56 columns. Joined tables need combinations. Is there a way that an equivalent of global variables could be used (I'm assuming using shared preferences would be more of an overhead). That is I could set the offsets just once from anywhere and then access them from anywhere (by anywhere I mean from within any activity or adpater)? To re-iterate, mainly to reduce maintenance overheads/issues and with consideration of run efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using the ***run once per activity*** to set column offset values, cannot be improved upon without introducing overheads.

Answer (score 1):

Each query can have different column Indexes, so it would not be a good idea to use table column Indexes.

There is no performance problem with `getColumnIndex()`, especially not when you're returning only a single row. (But to avoid additional checks for missing or wrong columns, you should use `getColumnIndexOrThrow()`, if possible.)

To reduce the amount of typing, write a helper function that calls both `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` and `getString()`/`getXxx()`.

Comment: re different column indexes. I'm aware and in the example you'll notice that I have, as an example, AISLES_COLUMN_ID  (equates to _ID) and AISLES_COLUMN_ID_FULL that includes the table name as a prefix (aisles_id). So this aspect is down to naming conventions and is covered.

Comment: re checking for missing columns. That's something I don't do as I use constants throughout;  in db creation, queries and when accessing/updating data (also assists writing the code accurately). I don't actually see a need. I may look into trying to determine what the actual overheads of using `getColumnIndex()` are. To me there must be some, as basically you're searching the cursor by a name to then extract the offset, which is then used to access the data.

Comment: Although reducing typing is good it's not really the object. The object is more to write code that is less susceptible to the introduction of errors due to duplicated code which may be missed or include mistakes. Perhaps I will end up using `cursor.getType(getColumnIndex(columnname))` throughout and risk the overheads :). Perhaps I need a little convincing though :). I greatly appreciate your input and I'll certainly consider helper functions.